# Search content from all columns in SharePoint 2010 list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I need a `SPQuery` (CAML query) to search content within all columns of SharePoint 2010 list.

Search the text from whole SharePoint list & give me columns according to result.

```
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Sample List");
                        if (list != null)
                        {
                            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                            query.Query = "***********";
                            SPListItemCollection FoundColl = list.GetItems(query);
                            DataTable dt = FoundColl.GetDataTable();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SharePoint 2010, we have one and only way to search in list is: **CAML**. It does not provide any API in C# like SharePoint  2013. So try to write a CAML including your all fields

```
<Where>
   <Or>
      <Or>
         <Or>
            <Contains>
               <FieldRef Name="Title" />
               <Value Type="Text">my key word</Value>
            </Contains>
            <Contains>
               <FieldRef Name="Col1" />
               <Value Type="Text">my key word</Value>
            </Contains>
         </Or>
         <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name="Col2" />
            <Value Type="Text">my key word</Value>
         </Contains>
      </Or>
      <Contains>
         <FieldRef Name="Col3" />
         <Value Type="Text">my key word</Value>
      </Contains>
   </Or>
</Where>
```

Assuming your fields are Title, Col1, Col2, Col3 and you want to search `"my key word"` inside your columns.

[U2U Caml Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Software) can help you for building CAML

As you have said in the comment that you have 42 columns, so it is difficult to write a CAML query. Alternatives can be iterating over the fields and build your query by concatenating the `string`.

Comment: I have already mentioned in comment that "I need query which can search in all columns. I can define columns one by one with contains but i need simple solution. I do have 42 Columns in my list". If is there any other alternative than please suggest me so i can work on.

Comment: Sorry. I did not see your comment in other answer. You can use **U2U Caml Query Builder** for building large CAML query.
http://www.u2u.be/Software

Comment: It was fine. It can work but i need alternative solution if possible like default search provided in SharePoint 2013 List.

Comment: I mentioned in my answer that SP 2010 does not have any Search API in C# like SP 2013

Comment: Alternatives can be iterating over the fields and build your query by concatenating the `string`

Answer (score -2):

Logic would be like below -

```
string queryVal = "ABC"
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Sample List");

if (list != null)
{
     SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
     query.Query = "columns contains queryVal";
     SPListItemCollection FoundColl = list.GetItems(query);
     DataTable dt = FoundColl.GetDataTable();
}
```

Comment: I need query which can search in all columns. I can define columns one by one with contains but i need simple solution. I do have 42 Columns in my list.